# ReactJS - Events is undefined, It won't render onChange event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, onchange

[image]

I'm trying to create a converter from inches to cm and feet to cm but I want to have only one input and to switch between them with buttons. I created a value `this.bol` set to neutral and some click events to change that value. Depending on that value the onChange event will listen and know which state to update but I get `events` is not defined.

Comment: you should not add images, since they could be taken down. insert code examples as text, so this question can stay relevant for future users reading it.

Comment: i thought it might be convinient and easier to read in a picture

Comment: it is not for several reasons I mentioned. Also it is not possible to edit the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you call the function without passing the event. The callback function you pass to `onChange` gets the event as first parameter and you have to manually pass it to you custom handler.

```
<input onChange={(event) => {
  return this.handler(event);
}}>
```